# Where can I get the latest version of Totem?

Tags: ppa, totem

I would like to install the latest version of Totem. I want to use a PPA or a .deb and I couldn't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it on the [launchpad page of totem](https://launchpad.net/totem)

Or alternatively on the [launchpad page for totem in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem)

**Edit:**
Sorry i thought there where PPA's somewhere on those sites.

There is also a [Totem page on gnome.org](http://projects.gnome.org/totem/)

Where it is said you should simply use `$ sudo apt-get install totem-gstreamer` which will install the latest stable(if you didn't change your `apt_preferences`) release.

If you explicitly want the latest release, no matter if stable or not you could add `-t unstable` to the `apt-get` command. Please see the man page for more info.

Comment: But the links you mention do not have any ppa or .deb files to download. The downloads section has only .tar.gz meaning compiling from source.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you especially want to use a PPA or a .deb?

Comment: I don't want to compile. I just want to do it with one or two clicks :)

Comment: I 've just did what you said. After installing totem-gstreamer I still have Totem 2.30.2 and Gstreamer 0.10.28 (and I never changed the apt_preferences).

Comment: You tagged your question with `10.04` so my guess is that you are using Lucid and you simply won't get a newer version, without implicitly saying which version you want. The command to install the latest version of totem would be `apt-get install totem=2.32.0` but as long as you don't add software sources for Maverick i don't think you will be able to download it. Your only hope in that case is a PPA or .deb, but I don't know where to find one. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Ricotz PPA also has it https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing/+packages