# How to install latest version of Totem Movie Player?

Tags: 12.04, updates, totem, media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get the latest version of Totem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23829/where-can-i-get-the-latest-version-of-totem)

The one thing I've found in Ubuntu is how the default apps are not usually or easily updated. Apps like Rhythmbox and Totem have gotten new releases since 12.04 came out and I was wondering if there's a PPA or anything I can add so I can have Totem and essentially other default apps up to date. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ubuntu **12.10** (Quantal) will likely be using Totem **3.4.3-0**, rather than **3.0.1-0** that was release with Ubuntu **12.04**.  However, this has only been released (for Quantal beta) quite recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most sure fire way is just to compile for your system.

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-sourcehandling.en.html

`apt-get install build-essential`

`apt-get build-dep package`

`apt-get source package` or `dget http://file-that-ends-in-dsc`

`cd package-*`

`dpkg-buildpackage`

However much of Totem's functionality is mostly gstreamer, so upgrading it doesn't change that much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to? New releases come with new bugs - Ubuntu updates them for you after they've been thoroughly tested for possible regressions.

Unless you need a feature that came out in the new release, then don't fuss over upgrading it.

If you really want to, it might not be as easy as Ubuntu makes it out for you - first thing I'd do is search Launchpad PPA's for it - and it's not in any, you'd have to compile it from source.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

- If dependencies allow, you can download the 12.10 `.deb` and install it.  I have done this a few times.  Monitor 12.10 for patch releases.
- Enable the `backports` repository in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and see if it is available there.  I've done this as well.
- Download the 12.10 source package and backport it yourself.  (As above monitor for patches.)
- Locate a PPA or other source for a `.deb` package of the release.  (This may not be as secure as the above options.)  Generally, this is more applicable for newer programs, or other programs which aren't yet in a mainstream repository.
- Find a compatible standalone binary distribution.  (Depending on the source it may be a security risk.)
- Install from source. (Generally not recommended, but usually reasonably secure.  )